# How to escape = in @queryparam annotation in jax rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a service that checks if the given url is present in the database. I'm using `@QueryParam` annotation but it is not returning the complete url for youtube, i.e., it is ignoring the video id.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can provide the sample code for more details

Comment: @Produces("application/xml")
public class checkAccountImpl
{ 
 @GETpublic void CheckAccounts(@QueryParam("url") String url){ }
}//in themethod, I'm checking with the databse and performing some operations on the url, but at this point its not taking the complete url

Answer (score 0):

You have just to [encode](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the query parameter before send it, for example to send:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y6120QOlsfU

encode it like this:

```
url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dy6120QOlsfU
```

and then in your Controller just decode it:

```
String result = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: I don't know what url the user will enter, how can I encode it then? Is there a way to obtain the complete url?

Comment: This is a front-end issue. Who is passing your value? A form? Javascript? Without any information or additional code is impossible to help you. As you said you don't have the url, that's because you have to encode it BEFORE passing it, otherwise you cannot obtain it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the java.net.URLEncoder and java.netURLDecoder to encode/decode URLs.
Maybe you should give a look on [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) that would solve your problem.